# Why won't PC laptop completely power off after upgrade to Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, power-management

I have recently upgraded from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 and it appears that it mostly successful. By and large I'm pretty happy with the upgrade however there is now a problem with turning off my laptop.

When I use any of the 'off' variations (shutdown/hibernate ext.) the laptop acts like its turning off and boils down to a low hum - but never actually turns off. Moreover the button becomes unresponsive to any further presses so that I can not turn on my computer without first enforcing a 'hard' shutdown by holding the button - which is bad for my laptop and will reduce its life considerably.

How can I resolve this?

Here's some info in case it's needed

```
Product name:HP Pavilion 15 Notebook PC 
BIOS:F.34-12/19/2014
Keyboard revision:77.35
Total memory:8.00 GB
Processor name:Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4288U CPU @ 2.60GHz
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting one.  Have you tried updating the Chipset Drivers, or installed a newer BIOS revision (if there is one).  One suggesting for the Chipset would be to obtain the latest driver from the Intel Website, rather than HP.

Comment: Try using command `shutdown -s -f -t 1` if that does not shutdown the computer completely, something is definitely broken. If it works, maybe your computer is entering sleep/hibernation instead of true shutdown.

Comment: Pressing the power button to turn off your laptop will not reduce its life in any way.

Comment: @mnmnc I just tried 'shutdown -s -f -t 1' and this showed the exact same behaviour.

Comment: @James no I have not tried this as I've not actually heard of Chipset drivers. I think this would be a last resort right? Installing a new BIOS seems rather drastic

Comment: @qasdfdsaq  Even if it doesn't reduce the laptops life (which I'm not convinced) you have to admit that having a laptop that wont turn off unless you hold the power button is not a good thing - especially given that it was advertised as a working upgrade.

Comment: Yes, hence I upvoted the question as ACPI issues with Windows 10 are quite common right now. A new BIOS is not drastic. There are two things that control power: the BIOS and the chipset/ACPI drivers in Windows. You should update both.

Comment: Yes, so BIOS updates aren't a massively drastic, most manufacturers these days will create an installer that does all the hard work for you, all you need to do is ensure your machine is connected to its charger and no applications are open.  Chipset drivers are the most common thing to try first though, have a look in Device Manager (Right-click on Computer > Manage) & see if there are any drivers missing and make sure they are installed also.

Comment: Check this out as well. It has exact same symptoms with couple of solutions provided: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_perf/windows-10-tp-fully-updated-will-not-shut-down/0b1c8893-8b43-4ebc-875b-8ae187e002d0?auth=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please downgrade Intel Management Engine Interface driver from v11xx to v9.5xx.
Sleep And Shutdown problem solved...
And also disable automatic update of drivers.