# Windows 10 Does not Shutdown Correctly

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, shutdown, dell-inspiron

I have a problem with my Windows 10 machine
When ever I try to Shutdown my laptop it looks like it did
but my Hardware is still Active.

The Light are On and if you listen carefully you will hear the fans are working
and when ever I try to open it it just doesn't work
because it's still working so I have to shutdown my laptop by holding the power button.

I had the same problem with Windows 8 but I fixed it by unchecking "Turn on fast startup (recommended)" from the Power Options but sadly no luck in Windows 10.

My laptop is Dell 3537 and I am running on Windows 10 Build 10240.

Comment: Edited your post - no need to apologies, believe me, your English is excellent.

Comment: Look here: https://superuser.com/questions/962949/why-wont-pc-laptop-completely-power-off-after-upgrade-to-windows-10#comment1317070_962949